# PDO multi-record insert trouble

Tags: pdo, insert

I am trying to do a multi-record insert statement using PDO with a MySQL database. After searching and working through some errors..I am at a point where I am stuck and need help.

inserting into 11-columns...and I believe there are 189 records to insert.

I have checked my ?'s array to ensure there are '11' ?'s in each () set.....and that there are 189 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), sets in my 'value array' I pass in.  So I think the problem lies with the 'data array' (and not the 'place holder' array).  (if that makes any sense)

Example of query echo'd out:
    QUERY: INSERT INTO fontEntries(date_entered, font_name, font_maker, font_format, optimized_for, font_price, font_image, font_url, description, youtube_id, ip_address) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), ......n

all 189 'sets' are there.

right now I'm stuck at an invalid parameter number error

my code:

```
<?php
$conn=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test;","root","");
//$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");


// displays all the file nodes
if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file('saberEntries.xml')){
    trigger_error('Error reading XML file', E_USER_ERROR);
}
//print_r($xml);
$totalCount = 0;
$ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$detailArray = array();
foreach($xml->entry as $fontEntry){
    global $totalCount;

    $details = array($fontEntry->fontName, $fontEntry->attributes()->submissionDate, $fontEntry->fontCreator. $fontEntry->fontFormat,$fontEntry->optimized,$fontEntry->fontPrice,$fontEntry->fontImage,$fontEntry->fontURL,$fontEntry->demoLink,$fontEntry->description,$ip_address);

    //$detailArray[] = $details;
    foreach($details as $item){
        $detailArray[] = $item;
    }
    $totalCount++;
    //echo ($totalCount + 1 '.) Array Check: '.$details[0] ."<br>");
}
echo "Total Entries in XML: $totalCount <br>";
echo "Total Array Length: ". count($detailArray) ."<br>";
//echo 'Array Check: '.$detailArray[0] ."<br>";

$qMarks = str_repeat('(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), ', count($detailArray)-1) . '(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
//echo 'Q-MARKS: '.$qMarks . '<br>';
//var_dump($detailArray) ."<br>";

$myQuery = "INSERT INTO fontEntries(date_entered, font_name, font_maker, font_format, optimized_for, font_price, font_image, font_url, description, youtube_id, ip_address) VALUES $qMarks";

$import_statement = $conn->prepare($myQuery);

$import_statement->execute($detailArray);   

//check is insert was successful
 if ($import_statement->execute()) {
    //true 
    echo 'INSERT SUCCESSFUL';
}else{
    //false
    echo 'INSERT FAILED <br>';
    $errorcode = $import_statement->errorCode();
    echo 'ERROR CODE: '.$errorcode .'<br>';
    $error = $import_statement->errorInfo();
    echo 'ERROR CODE 2: '.$error .'<br>';
}
?>
```

error:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\wamp\www\xml_tests\simpleXML_test.php on line 79
```

Line 79:

```
$import_statement->execute($detailArray);
```

Anybody point where my error is?  Thanks.

working code: (thanks to Your common sense's advice/help)

```
<?php
$conn=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test;","root","");
//$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

// displays all the file nodes
if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file('target_xml.xml')){
    trigger_error('Error reading XML file', E_USER_ERROR);
}

$totalCount = 0;
$ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

foreach($xml->entry as $fontEntry){

    $details = array($fontEntry->attributes()->submissionDate, $fontEntry->fontName, $fontEntry->fontCreator, $fontEntry->fontFormat, $fontEntry->optimized, $fontEntry->fontPrice, $fontEntry->fontImage, $fontEntry->fontURL, $fontEntry->description, $fontEntry->demoLink, $ip_address);    

    //dump/parse into one big/long (1-dimensional) array to pass to PDO
    foreach($details as $item){
        $detailArray[] = $item;
    }

    $totalCount++;
    echo ('Entry#: '.$totalCount.'<br/>');
}
echo "Total Entries in XML: $totalCount <br>";
echo "Total Array Length: ". count($detailArray) ."<br><br>";

$qMarks = str_repeat('(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), ', $totalCount-1 ). '(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
//echo 'Q-MARKS: <br>'.$qMarks . '<br>';
//print_r($detailArray) ."<br>";
//var_dump($detailArray) ."<br>";

$myQuery = "INSERT INTO fontEntries(date_entered, font_name, font_maker, font_format, optimized_for, font_price, font_image, font_url, description, youtube_id, ip_address) VALUES $qMarks";

$import_statement = $conn->prepare($myQuery);

$import_statement->execute($detailArray);   

//check is insert was successful
 if ($import_statement->execute()) {
    //true 
    echo 'INSERT SUCCESSFUL';
}else{
    //false
    echo 'INSERT FAILED <br>';
    $errorcode = $import_statement->errorCode();
    echo 'ERROR CODE: '.$errorcode .'<br>';
    $error = $import_statement->errorInfo();
    echo 'ERROR CODE 2: '.$error .'<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: what's all this `$details .=` business for?

Comment: it was an alternate approach to try and solve my 'errors'...  just a way to build a 'string'... instead of trying to plop it into an array. (both yield the same result/error)

Comment: Why did you left it here in code then? Think it will make it easier to read and comprehend? See the answer below.

Comment: I left in there to outline the attempts I had tried.  (cant make everyone happy.. some want it all and all methods you tried.. some only want a snippet)..  I feel its best to provide everything so there is no lack of 'background' in seeking help/advice)

I will try this when I get home:

    `foreach ($details as $item) $detailArray[] = $item;`

Comment: why did my question get downvoted? (and where is my comment from earlier?) (and your suggested solution?)

Comment: It didnt work.  (same errors)

I have updated the original post with the code according to your suggestion(s).

Comment: I understand its 'fun' to belittle people who come to a 'help forum' looking for help..lol.  But does it come with any actual help? :)

Comment: uncomment last two lines and count question marks and values by hand

Answer (score 0):

instead of     `$detailArray[] = $details;`  make it

```
foreach ($details as $item) $detailArray[] = $item;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? This got in the low-quality queue.

Comment: SO to be clear:

this:
    $details .= $fontEntry->fontName .', '; ....etc..etc (building a comma delimited string is -not- the correct way.. 

I should be doing:

    $details = array($fontEntry->fontName,......'n');

Type of approach, actually populating an ARRAY...

I'm trying to learn from my mistake(s) and the correct approach...  so the failure lies(lied) with trying to use a 'string' instead of an array?  even though the finally piece fo data passed into the PDO instance was/is an array?

Thanks.

Comment: the failure lies with trying to use array of arrays instead of an array

Comment: ok.. so the question marks/place holders need to be 'grouped' in groups of 11.... but the actual values need to be 1 LONG 1-dimensional array?  not an array of arrays with each index having the 11 values in each?  I thought I had tried that.. witht he detailsAttay() having a total count of 1890 (189 x 11).. and still got param/value count error..

Comment: 189 x 11 = 2079 if my pocket calculator isn't broken

Comment: @ycs- thank you for your help and advice.

(mainly letting me know things needed to be a 1-dimensional array to eventually pass as well).

I also need to adjust the count for the  string repeat, which is why I kept getting the param count error after adding in your line of code/solution.

    `$qMarks = str_repeat('(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), ', $totalCount-1 ). '(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';`
in case anyone stumbles upon this thread. needs to be updated as well

Comment: *still dont understand why the downvote?  legit questions.  full background.  code given, attempts shown. ?   Just for fun I guess?